# Should WepApi controller return viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The WebApi is suited well for Single Page Apps which use javascript ViewModel with KnockoutJS.

Should my WebApi return a c# ViewModel which gets converted to a Json ViewModel then.

Or should my WebApi controller return a business object and create a javascript viewmodel?

I have never seen the first in any WebApi tutorial and I wonder why.

Comment: I know this question is answered but when you say "converted to a Json ViewModel" could you elaborate for clarity?  In the client with Knockout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should my WebApi return a c# ViewModel which gets converted to a Json ViewModel then

Yes absolutely. This way you have total control over what gets sent to the client. Also if you decide to change your underlying business models in a new version of your API for example you will not break your existing clients. All you need to do is adapt the mapping between your business models and your view models.

> Or should my WebApi controller return a business object and create a javascript viewmodel?

No, never sent your business models to a client. You should always use view models.

> I have never seen the first in any WebApi tutorial and I wonder why.

I have never seen the first in any ASP.NET MVC tutorial neither, and me too I wonder why. Probably because the tutorials are not covering real world application scenarios but represent oversimplified examples that would allow you to get started with some technology. It's unfortunate because so many people follow those tutorials without realizing the importance of using view models in real world applications. StackOverflow is a great place to see how many people are actually not aware of the importance of view models.

Comment: I was watching the SPApp tutorial from pluralsight/john papa and there is not even a model folder in the web project and he is really returning the domain entity to the view. Such a sample from such a guy I just could not believe it hehe.

Comment: `and he is really returning the domain entity to the view` - oh I am really sorry to hear that.

Comment: Interesting how much confusion is already out there. Many posts assume they have to use their Entities as View Models b/c of those pluralsight and asp.net tutorials

Comment: @Elisa: You're talking about Code Camper example from John Papa, right? His entities match exactly what he needs in the view. What would you return from WebApi instead?

Comment: That's probably because he designed his database/entities to match exactly what will be shown in the view. Remember that this is not always the case. For example you might already have an existing database and domain models which you would like to reuse in your Web API. You would then design view models that would be specifically tailored for the requirements of the view and what needs to be transported over the wire but internally your Web API will manipulate your existing domain model.

Comment: @Nenad yes the code camper sample with the terrible Repository Factory instead of using a DI tool... ;-) I would also return the needs of the view... I think in the code camper sample he wanted to avoid automapper and keep it simple.

Comment: @Elisa: He returns exactly what he needs in the view. So no point mapping it 1-on-1 just to name 2nd class "CarViewModel". And additionally, he uses breezejs library on top of WebAPI. That let's him query entities with OData, construct LINQ like queries on the client, cache query result on client and track changes of data too. Highly optimized network usage for mobile apps.

Comment: DTO ViewModel same thing look at Code Camper. Either the DTO/ViewModel is going to get passed to business logic (Module) on the client or the server. It is so simple to pass a DTO or a ViewModel to Module at either end I don't see the need to demonstrate it ? Its an extra line of code in the Web API controller where the DTO View Model is passed in and out usually prior to the Data Layer

Comment: Hey @DarinDimitrov what could I do if my Web API controller is actually converting the model into a viewmodel but that process just takes way too long? At the moment it works great when there are a couple of hundreds of records, but with a couple of thousands it just goes mad. Any guidance would be really appreciated